# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/html/cdf/application/models/Appointment_model.php on line 17

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

This is the error on the screen
(I generated the code using crudigniter)
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Parsing Error

Message: syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

Filename: models/Appointment_model.php

Line Number: 17

Backtrace:
Here is my code

```
/*
*Appointments Controller in controllers/Appointments.php
*/
<?php
/* 
 * Generated by CRUDigniter v2.0 Beta 
 * www.crudigniter.com
 */

class Appointment extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Appointment_model');
    } 

    /*
     * Listing of appointments
     */
    function index()
    {
        $data['appointments'] = $this->Appointment_model->get_all_appointments();
        $this->load->view('appointment/index',$data);
    }

    /*
     * Adding a new appointment
     */
    function add()
    {   
        if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST) > 0)     
        {   
            $params = array(
                'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
                'appointee_name' => $this->input->post('appointee_name'),
                'appointment_reason' => $this->input->post('appointment_reason'),
                'appointment_date' => $this->input->post('appointment_date'),
                'recorded_by' => $this->input->post('recorded_by'),
                'dateadded' => $this->input->post('dateadded'),
            );

            $appointment_id = $this->Appointment_model->add_appointment($params);
            redirect('appointment/index');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('appointment/add');
        }
    }  

    /*
     * Editing a appointment
     */
    function edit($)
    {   
        // check if the appointment exists before trying to edit it
        $appointment = $this->Appointment_model->get_appointment($);

        if(isset($appointment['']))
        {
            if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST) > 0)     
            {   
                $params = array(
                    'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
                    'appointee_name' => $this->input->post('appointee_name'),
                    'appointment_reason' => $this->input->post('appointment_reason'),
                    'appointment_date' => $this->input->post('appointment_date'),
                    'recorded_by' => $this->input->post('recorded_by'),
                    'dateadded' => $this->input->post('dateadded'),
                );

                $this->Appointment_model->update_appointment($,$params);            
                redirect('appointment/index');
            }
            else
            {   
                $data['appointment'] = $this->Appointment_model->get_appointment($);

                $this->load->view('appointment/edit',$data);
            }
        }
        else
            show_error('The appointment you are trying to edit does not exist.');
    } 

    /*
     * Deleting appointment
     */
    function remove($)
    {
        $appointment = $this->Appointment_model->get_appointment($);

        // check if the appointment exists before trying to delete it
        if(isset($appointment['']))
        {
            $this->Appointment_model->delete_appointment($);
            redirect('appointment/index');
        }
        else
            show_error('The appointment you are trying to delete does not exist.');
    }

}
```

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ILAz.png)

Comment: Please mention which line is line no 17 .

Comment: `function edit($)`

Comment: `$this->Appointment_model->update_appointment($,$params);` Figure out what's supposed to go where that lonely `$` is ;-). Not to mention you best fix this one too: `$data['appointment'] = $this->Appointment_model->get_appointment($);`

Comment: post your model and mention line 17.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to name your variables correctly. $ isn't a valid variable

```
function edit($)
{   
    // check if the appointment exists before trying to edit it
    $appointment = $this->Appointment_model->get_appointment($);
```

please change the ($) to a variable. eg ($id) and update the `get_appointment($id)`

```
function edit($id)
{   
    // check if the appointment exists before trying to edit it
    $appointment = $this->Appointment_model->get_appointment($id);
```